# Php echo into tag

Tags: php, tags, html

How can I add classes on the `echo` returns?

```
    <div class="author_sidebar">
    <?php if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), 75 );
echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' );
    ?>
    </div>
```

I managed to solve the problem by rapping the `echo` returns in `divs` this then allowed me to add `classes` into the `divs`

Comment: Which text do you want to change and into what? Your code simply displays an image and the user's name. Ps. Note that you're missing a closing `}` there.

Comment: So I want the users name to have a tag on the HTML so I can style it easier :')

Comment: You mean add an attribute, like a CSS class. There isn't a generic way to do that. You'd need to refer to the documentation for each function to see if there's a way to do it. The simplest way would be to just wrap the output in a div with a class on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to wrap an HTML tag around the user display names, you can simply close and open the PHP tags:

```
<div class="author_sidebar">
  <?php if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) { ?>
    <div class="foo"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), 75 ); ?></div>
    <div class="bar"><?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); ?>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to wrap the html echoed by get_avatar or get_the_author_meta @swissspidy is totally right.

If you want to add some css class to `<img>` tag echoed by get_avatar, you can add it by passing it as an argument (as explained in the documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar).

```
$args = ['class' => 'foo'];     
echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), 75, null, null, $args )
```